# copy entire data from one workbook to another using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a "object variable or with block variable not set" error message when running the following code. What is wrong with the code?

```
        Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As        Integer
        Dim mainworkBook As Workbook

       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       directory = "C:\Users\425410\Desktop\MYExcel\"
       fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")  
    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set x = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
    Windows("Book3.xlsm").Activate

    Set ws1 = x.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets(1)

    With ws1
        .Cells.Copy ws2.Cells
             y.Close True
             x.Close False
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user3514930 commented you need to set y to a workbook object.

Added some extra code edits.

```
'<<I think grouping similar types together when declaring variables is clearer than OP 
'<<Also I prefer all declarations at the start of subroutines

Dim directory As String, fileName As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
directory = "C:\Users\425410\Desktop\MYExcel\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")  

Set x = Workbooks.Open(directory & fileName)
Windows("Book3.xlsm").Activate

Set y = Workbooks("someopenBook") '<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Set ws1 = x.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = y.Sheets(1)

'<<not sure why you have the workbook close lines within the With block
With ws1
    .Cells.Copy ws2.Cells
End With

y.Close True
x.Close False
```